# Transform Source Data from HDFS and transform through Talend

Tags: hive, hbase, hdfs, talend, ignite

We are trying to source the data from HDFS, Hive, Hbase & Apache Ignite with web services and do the relevant transformation with Talend, and then load the data into downstream systems.

I am seeking help if we can use particular software that can be integrated with the hadoop cluster to help us achieve this

Comment: Did you try asking here https://help.talend.com/display/HOME/Welcome ?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done there. I will try right away. thank you

Answer (score 0):

To access data on HDFS or Hive you need to use [WebHcatalog](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+UsingWebHCat) :

> WebHCat is the REST API for HCatalog, a table and storage management
>   layer for Hadoop

[Hcatlog](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+UsingHCat#HCatalogUsingHCat-HCatalogWebAPI) is :

> HCatalog’s table abstraction presents users with a relational view of
>   data in the Hadoop distributed file system (HDFS) and ensures that
>   users need not worry about where or in what format their data is
>   stored

Data on Hbase are accessible through Hbase Rest api, see [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#external_apis), or you can create Hive table on top of Hbase by the [HbaseIntegration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration) feature in Hive, then access them through WebHcatalog.

Comment: That's not an answer. Talend have connections to HDFS\Hive itself so I guess the question should be addressed to their support\help site

Comment: I know that talend can connect to HDFS, but he asked `with web services` and talend does not use web service to access Hadoop. The answer is well aligned with the question.